# How do you write an SQL query where you can check if different rows have the same value in one of the fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, dml

So I've created some tables using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Staff` (
  `StaffID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `StaffName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `StaffAddress` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `StaffEmailAddress` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `StaffPhoneNo` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `Position` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Workload` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Supervisor` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StaffID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staff_works_campaign` (
`CampaignID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`StaffID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`SalaryGrade` Integer NOT NULL,
`isSup` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
`StaffName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`StaffID`, `CampaignID`), 
CONSTRAINT `FK_StaffID3` FOREIGN KEY (`StaffID`) REFERENCES `Staff` (`StaffID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_CampaignID2` FOREIGN KEY (`CampaignID`) REFERENCES `Advertising_Campaign` (`CampaignID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Which gives the tables:

[image: Table1]
[[image: Table2[2]]

So basically I want to create a query where it returns the StaffNames of all Full time staff members whose supervisors were not managers of campaigns they worked on. 
My approach on this was to first filter the non-fulltime workers out:

```
select s.StaffName
from staff s
where s.Workload = 'Full Time';
```

Which gives me all the Full time workers. The next step is figuring our whether they work in a campaign that is managed by one of their supervisors.

My idea is to see if the `staff_works_campaign.staffname = staff.supervisor`
for a full-time worker when the campaignIDs are the same as the non-supervisor worker (aka the supervisor and the worker are both working on the same campaign).

I am unsure at how to query based on the campaignIDs being the same and adding on the conditional `staff_works_campaign.staffname = staff.supervisor.`
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join both tables twice, once for the staff member and once for the supervisor.

```
SELECT s.staffName
FROM Staff AS s
JOIN Staff AS sup ON s.Supervisor = sup.StaffName
JOIN staff_words_campaign AS c ON c.StaffID = s.StaffID
JOIN staff_words_campaign AS csup ON csup.StaffID = sup.StaffID AND c.CampaignID = csup.CampaignID
```